# creating an array of classes in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am an absolute beginner to c# and I need some help with creating an array of classes.

```
class container {
    public string name;
    string details;
    string destination;

    public void get_all(){
      Console.WriteLine(name + "\n" + details + "\n" + destination);
    }
    public void set_name() {
      Console.WriteLine("enter name : ");
      name = Console.ReadLine();

      Console.WriteLine("enter details : ");
      details = Console.ReadLine();

      Console.WriteLine("enter destination: ");
      destination = Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
```

main :

```
class MainClass {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
       
      for (int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++){
        var cont[i] = new container();
      }

      cont[1].set_name();
      cont[1].get_all();


    }
```

I want to declare an array of container and set the second container of the array (as you can see in the last 3 lines) but I can't do it, can you help me?

Comment: What is wrong with your original code? Did you get some exception?

Comment: @Fabio Unhandled Exception:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at ex.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in <a1c9c743864949bc89998476dd37fe89>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at ex.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in <a1c9c743864949bc89998476dd37fe89>:0 
exit status 1

Comment: What is `ban`? You probably just need `var cont = new container[10];` before the loop. Then, you can use `cont[i]` inside the loop.

Comment: @Fabio this is the original code

Comment: alright let me try

Comment: Code in `main` class is not full, because current code wouldn't even compile, can you post complete example. Notice that `cont` array is not defined anywhere

Comment: what's con? where is it defined? also your class does not have properties

Comment: @Nonik, does class need properties? ;)

Comment: @Nonik you mean ban, I translated the code in English and forgot to translate that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create array of "containers" and set values for second container.

```
public class MainClass 
{
  public static void Main(string[] args) 
  {
    var containers = new container[10];
    for (int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
    {
      containers[i] = new container();
    }

    containers[1].set_name();
    containers[1].get_all();
  }
}
```

Will be good if you start following c# coding conventions from the beginning. IT is very important that our code style is consistent, because now days we work in the teams.

For example following [General Naming Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions) your code will look like below

```
public class Container 
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  private string _details;
  private string _destination;

  public void GetAll()
  {
    Console.WriteLine(Name + "\n" + _details + "\n" + _destination);
  }

  public void SetName() 
  {
    Console.WriteLine("enter name : ");
    Name = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("enter details : ");
    _details = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("enter destination: ");
    _destination = Console.ReadLine();
  }
}

public class MainClass 
{
  public static void Main(string[] args) 
  {
    var containers = new Container[10];
    for (int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
    {
      containers[i] = new Container();
    }

    containers[1].SetName();
    containers[1].GetAll();
  }
}
```

Comment: no, it does not work I get this error
main.cs(22,14): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `void', expecting `class', `delegate', `enum', `interface', `partial', `ref', or `struct'
main.cs(22,31): error CS1514: Unexpected symbol `[', expecting `.' or `{'
main.cs(22,31): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `]', expecting `class', `delegate', `enum', `interface', `partial', `ref', or `struct'
main.cs(24,22): error CS1530: Keyword `new' is not allowed on namespace elements
main.cs(24,25): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `co ....

Comment: @Newdude, wrap `Main` method with the class

Comment: @Fabio while you're teaching, would you mind also giving some lessons on C# naming conventions? As is the `container`[sic] class makes me wanna stick pins in my eyes :)

Comment: can you(if you have time) tell me why you wrapped the "Main" class into "MainClass"?

Comment: @Newdude Main in `public static void Main` is not a class (a blueprint for an object instance), it is a *method* - code that performs an action

Answer (score 1):

To declare an array you can write

```
Container[] cont = new Container[10];
```

You can use **var** as well

```
var cont = new Container[10];
```